# Can you combine pd.wide_to_long with the creation of a multiindex?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe in a wide format that looks like this:

```
citydata = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Trip Date','City 1 Name','City 2 Name','City 3 Name','City 1 Cost','City 2 Cost','City 3 Cost','City 1 Hotel','City 2 Hotel','City 3 Hotel'])
citydata.loc[0] = ['2023-01-15','London','Paris','Barcelona',5500,4375,2530,"Marriott","Hilton","W"]
citydata.loc[1] = ['2023-08-15','Sydney','Auckland','Beijing',9500,2300,11000,"Peninsula","Meridien","AirBnb"]
citydata
```

| Trip Date | City 1 Name | City 2 Name | City 3 Name | City 1 Cost | City 2 Cost | City 3 Cost | City 1 Hotel | City 2 Hotel | City 3 Hotel |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-01-15 | London | Paris | Barcelona | 5500 | 4375 | 2530 | Marriott | Hilton | W |
| 2023-08-15 | Sydney | Auckland | Beijing | 9500 | 2300 | 11000 | Peninsula | Meridien | AirBnb |

I want to use pd.wide_to_long (or another function like melt?) to remove the City 1, 2, and 3 distinction, have a long format, and have simple columns for City Name, City Cost, and City Hotel. The end result would be:

| Trip Date | City Name | City Cost | City Hotel |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-01-15 | London | 5500 | Marriott |
| 2023-01-15 | Paris | 4375 | Hilton |
| 2023-01-15 | Barcelona | 2530 | W |
| 2023-08-15 | Sydney | 9500 | Peninsula |
| 2023-08-15 | Auckland | 2300 | Meridien |
| 2023-08-15 | Beijing | 11000 | AirBnb |

I can't seem to figure out how pd.wide_to_long can do this while preserving the trip date index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert the columns to multiindex then reshape using stack

```
df = citydata.set_index('Trip Date')
df.columns = df.columns.str.rsplit(' ', 1, expand=True)
df = df.stack(0).droplevel(1).add_prefix('City ')
```

---

```
print(df)
            City Cost City Hotel  City Name
Trip Date                                  
2023-01-15       5500   Marriott     London
2023-01-15       4375     Hilton      Paris
2023-01-15       2530          W  Barcelona
2023-08-15       9500  Peninsula     Sydney
2023-08-15       2300   Meridien   Auckland
2023-08-15      11000     AirBnb    Beijing
```

Answer (score 2):

You can *pre-process* the columns names so they can match with [`wide_to_long`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.wide_to_long.html) :

```
pat = r"(City)\s*(\d+)\s*(\w+)" # to match "City +1digit and a name-suffix"
citydata.columns = citydata.columns.str.replace(pat, r"\1 \3\2", regex=True)

stubs = ["City Name", "City Cost", "City Hotel"]

out = (
    pd.wide_to_long(
        citydata, stubnames=stubs, i="Trip Date", j="_")
        .sort_index().droplevel(-1).reset_index()
)
```

Output :

```
print(out)

    Trip Date  City Name  City Cost City Hotel
0  2023-01-15     London       5500   Marriott
1  2023-01-15      Paris       4375     Hilton
2  2023-01-15  Barcelona       2530          W
3  2023-08-15     Sydney       9500  Peninsula
4  2023-08-15   Auckland       2300   Meridien
5  2023-08-15    Beijing      11000     AirBnb
```

Answer (score 2):

One option is with [pyjanitor's pivot_longer](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/api/functions/#janitor.functions.pivot.pivot_longer):

```py
# pip install pyjanitor
import pandas as pd
import janitor
(citydata
.pivot_longer(
    index='Trip Date', 
    names_to = ('.value', '.value'), 
    names_sep = r"\d\s", 
    sort_by_appearance=True)
)
    Trip Date  City Name  City Cost City Hotel
0  2023-01-15     London       5500   Marriott
1  2023-01-15      Paris       4375     Hilton
2  2023-01-15  Barcelona       2530          W
3  2023-08-15     Sydney       9500  Peninsula
4  2023-08-15   Auckland       2300   Meridien
5  2023-08-15    Beijing      11000     AirBnb
```